# How to convert org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema instance to a string?

Tags: eclipse, xsd, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse ***org.eclipse.xsd.XSDSchema*** instance. I need to print the schema as a string.

Despite a day long effort, I am not able to get a solution except for loading it to a eclipse resource and saving it to disk. But this is not solving my purpose. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! After scanning through the Eclipse EMF codebase, found a way. The code snippet below prints the XSDSchema instance to console.

```
public static void printXSDSchema(XSDSchema xsdSchema){
    XSDResourceImpl.serialize(System.out, xsdSchema.getDocument());
}
```